# Having just installed qiskit 0.43.2 on Windows 10 64b, the 'Get started' example fails on 'from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator'

Tags: qiskit

The python script says:

> `from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator`

and fails with complaints about DLLs:

> (.qit) C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT>python test.py Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT\test.py", line
> 2, in 
> from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator   File "C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT.qit\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_aer_*init*_.py",
> line 70, in 
> from qiskit_aer.aerprovider import AerProvider   File "C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT.qit\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_aer\aerprovider.py",
> line 21, in 
> from .backends.aer_simulator import AerSimulator   File "C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT.qit\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_aer\backends_*init*_.py",
> line 17, in 
> from .aer_simulator import AerSimulator   File "C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT.qit\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_aer\backends\aer_simulator.py",
> line 24, in 
> from .aerbackend import AerBackend, AerError   File "C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT.qit\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_aer\backends\aerbackend.py",
> line 35, in 
> from .aer_compiler import compile_circuit, assemble_circuits, generate_aer_config   File
> "C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT.qit\Lib\site-packages\qiskit_aer\backends\aer_compiler.py",
> line 34, in 
> from qiskit_aer.backends.controller_wrappers import AerCircuit, AerConfig ImportError: DLL load failed while importing
> controller_wrappers: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

The machine is:

> Édition   Windows 10 Famille Version  22H2

> Installé le   ‎04/‎05/‎2023

> Build du système d’exploitation   19045.3086

> Expérience    Windows Feature

> Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Python is:

> (.qit) C:\Users\chauv\Documents\QIT>python --version

> Python 3.11.4

Qiskit stuff is:

> qiskit               0.43.2

> qiskit-aer           0.12.1

> qiskit-ibmq-provider 0.20.2

> qiskit-terra         0.24.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
jmc

Comment: I suggest that such a technical issue is raised in Qiskit's GitHub instead. See, e.g., https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-metapackage/issues/1436.